# Access data of associative array inside associative array

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to access data of an associative array inside an associative array?

For instance,

```
foo = {
  subFooA: 2,
  subFooB: subFooA
}
```

or

```
foo = {
  subFooA: 2
}

foo = {
  subFooB: subFooA
}
```

-Edit-
Thank you for the answers... so I assume it is not possible for this

```
filter = {
    leadlag: {
        parameters: {
            K: 1,
            fz: 20,
            fp: 40,
            wz: 2*math.pi*20,
            wp: 2*math.pi*40
        }
    }
}

filter.leadlag.continuous = {
    a: [filter.leadlag.parameters.K*filter.leadlag.parameters.wp*filter.leadlag.parameters.wz, filter.leadlag.parameters.K*filter.leadlag.parameters.wp],
    b: [filter.leadlag.parameters.wp*filter.leadlag.parameters.wz, filter.leadlag.parameters.wz]
}
```

to be done more easily?

Comment: In JS these are not called "associative arrays"; they're called "objects".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your question v 2.0:

Yes it is possible and readable with a helper variable which holds the reference to the object.

```js
var filter = {
        leadlag: {
            parameters: {
                K: 1,
                fz: 20,
                fp: 40,
                wz: 2 * Math.PI * 20,
                wp: 2 * Math.PI * 40
            }
        }
    },
    p = filter.leadlag.parameters; // helper variable for better accessing

filter.leadlag.continuous = {
    a: [p.K *  p.wp * p.wz, p.K * p.wp],
    b: [p.wp * p.wz,  p.wz]
}
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(filter, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, you may follow different patterns as well:

```
var foo = {}
foo.subFooB = foo.subFooA = 2;
```

I always prefer using setter functions though as a cleaner approach:

```
function setFoo() {
  return 2;
}
var foo = {
  subfooA: setFoo(),
  subFooB: setFoo()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you take a look at my edit?

Answer (score 0):

The first is not possible, while with the second you were almost there:

```
var foo = {
    subFooA: 2
};

foo.subFooB = foo.subFooA;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you take a look at my edit?